# promise status code pending in Axios put request

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, axios

I am trying to perform edit action in react-redux. When I edit a form, it does not perform update action. I got `500 Internal Server Error` in my `Network's Status Code`. 
In my action, I have this code:

```
export function updateStandup(id, standups) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios({
      headers: authHeader(),
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `${ROOT_URL}/standups/${id}${API_KEY}`,
      data: standups
    }).then(response => {
      dispatch(success(response))
    })
  }

  function success(response) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_STANDUP',
      payload: response
    }
  }
}
```

And in my reducer I have following code:

```
export function standup(state = {}, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_STANDUP':
      return {
        standup: action.payload
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
 }
```

Will anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: In your code I don't see any problem, but by the description I guess it's problem with your api. If you can add more details about error on api side, that will help in solving your problem.

Comment: HTTP 500 means that request hit the backend but the backend failed to process the request. You need to check if server sends more info about what happened inside request body. There might be a useful error message.

Comment: @Swapnil - Thank you for your suggestion. I had a problem with my backend update action which is solved now.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - Yes, that was the problem. Thank you for your answer.